# I'm having trouble extracting the year from the date column of this particular dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

`#Adjust Date Info`

`TSLA['date'] = TSLA['date'].astype(str)`

`TSLA['date'] = pd.to_datetime(TSLA['date'])`

The datatype of both columns is object.

Ive tried using `.astype(str)` on the date column thenn using a lambda function to extract the YYYY-MM-DD but the datatype doesn't change. It doesn't throw up an error either when applying the `.astype(str)`

`.to_datetime` doesn't work either.

There are no missing values in either column. I'd appreciate any opinions as to what i'm doing incorrectly?

Since i am unable to add images for now, the date column has the following values: YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS-HH-MM-SS

Comment: Frequently Needed Answers 
Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Also, please include the full commands along with their exact errors.

Comment: I've edited to include the commands used. There were no errors. The command seems to work fine but `df.info` says the data type for date is still object.

Comment: Strange, the `pd.to_datetime` line should work. Just to confirm, run `TSLA['date'] = pd.to_datetime(TSLA['date'])` again and post the output of `TSLA.dtypes`

Comment: One more thing, i didn't realize a picture of the dataframe didn't show up. The date column consists of the following items : YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS-HH-MM-SS

o/p :
 title    object
date     object
dtype: object

Comment: Try strptime which parses a string into a date

Answer (score 1):

well I don't know that what you are trying to do but as you mentioned in the heading of your question that you want to extract the year,so for doing this:-

```
TSLA['date'] = pd.to_datetime(TSLA['date'])
TSLA['year']=TSLA['date'].dt.year
```

Comment: when your series is in `datetime` dtype it does

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it seems that
`TSLA['date'] = pd.to_datetime(TSLA['date'],utc = True)`

followed by:

`TSLA['date'] = TSLA['date'].dt.date`

got me the values i wanted i.e. YYYY-MM-DD.